Type trait providing the static member of a struct/class if available
I want to have a type trait for T that returns the value of a static member 'X' if it exists in T, otherwise a default value.
It can be done this way
// we define our type trait here 
template<typename T>  struct get_X  {  static constexpr int value = -1;  };

// and a specialization for types holding the required member
template<typename T>  static constexpr bool has_X = requires { T::X; };
template<typename T>  requires(has_X<T>) struct get_X<T>  {  static constexpr int value = T::X;  };

struct foo  {  static constexpr int X = 3;  };
struct bar  {  static constexpr int Y = 5;  };

static_assert (get_X<foo>::value ==  3);
static_assert (get_X<bar>::value == -1);

int main()  {}

This code works but is pretty cumbersome.
Moreover, if I want to have different type traits for other members like 'get_Y', it could lead to a lot of code.
Question: is there a simpler way to define such a type trait ?

I hesitate to say it, but if you're defining many similar traits that differ only in the name of the member you're detecting ... a macro will be easiest.

I think you're overcomplicating : Why not just make a constexpr function. template<T> static constexpr int GetX(return T::X'} and then static_assert( GetX<foo>() == 3).

See this answer in the dupe that uses a simple constexpr if and requires

Using if constexpr, you don't need partial specialisations:
template<typename T>
inline constexpr decltype(auto) get_X_v = []() -> decltype(auto) {
  if constexpr (requires { T::x; }) {
    return T::x;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
}();

You might be able to inline this into wherever you use it and get rid of the trait entirely.
